# rake db:create - rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, web-scraping

Hi im trying to follow this link to create a scraper and I am stuck trying to create a db
https://towardsdatascience.com/job-board-scraping-with-rails-872c432ed2c8

I get this error when typing `rake db:create` I've tried creating inside and outside the folder and I get this error I am not sure why, thank you very much. I have been closely following the link so I have all the same files and am sure everything was installed properly.

```rb
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::InvalidConfigurationError: 
'{ default =>  }' is not a valid configuration. Expected '' to be a URL string or a Hash.
```

This is my database.yml file

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
<<: *default  
database: scraper_development

test:
<<: *default
database: scraper_test

production:
<<: *default
url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %> 

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

### Update

Thanks for the pointer I had [the `database.yml` file] indented but I though an error told me to remove tabs. new issue now:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'scraper_development' database.
Please check your configuration.

rails aborted!

PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you get the same error when you run: `ENV='test' rails db:create`? Is the PostgreSQL gem actually installed (from Terminal, run `gem list pg`)? Do you have PostgreSQL on your machine (from Terminal, run `postgres --version`)?

Comment: env='test' gave me the same error

Comment: also gem list pg showed I have pg version 1.2.3 and Postgres --version shows I have postgreSQL 13.0

Answer (score 1):

The file is in [YAML format](https://yaml.org/). The sub-items must be indented.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default  
  database: scraper_development
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I had it indented but I though an error told me to remove tabs. new issue now :--> could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'scraper_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: @bnhamood126 Your Postgres database is not running. I see your tutorial doesn't explain how to set up Postgres or what Postgres is. You'll have to find and follow a tutorial for setting up Postgres.

Comment: @bnhamood126, I suggest [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres#setting-up-postgres), you can skip the "Installing Requirements" section. Also be sure to mark Schwern's answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can add " gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0' "  to the gem file and make the necessary settings in the YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and what I did was to fix the indentation, and then it worked.

The `database.yml` file is in [YAML format.](https://yaml.org/) so make sure the sub-items are indented correctly. Please check the example below on how you are supposed to indent it.

`This is how your database.yml file should look like`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default  
  database: scraper_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: scraper_test

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```